# Change IEEEtran citation with \citeform

Tags: bibliographies, citing

My school's thesis office requires citations that look like [1]-[4] and [2],[5]. IEEEtran is giving me [1-4] and [2, 5]. I tried to override this with \citeform with the following:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\renewcommand\citeform[1]{[#1]}
```

This results in added brackets around the numbers, but keeps the original brackets from IEEEtran. The result looks like [[1]-[4]] and [[2], [5]]. I'm positive it is adding brackets inside because I can change \citeform to give the result of [(1)-(4)] and [(2), (5)].

What changes can I make to get the result I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following two lines might work.

```
\def\citepunct{], [}
\def\citedash{]--[}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that you did not use IEEEtran.cls. For other cls file, the method described above should also work, although I am not 100% sure whether it works for all cls. You just need to copy the corresponding two lines to your TeX file.

Comment: You shall not cgange class files unless you own them and are the copyright holder.

Comment: Actually, you do not have to change the class file. Redefining those two macros would just work.

Comment: It should work, because of the usage of package `cite`. But you should use `\renewcommand` in LaTeX instead of `\def`.